# How to link textFiledshouldReturn func to Action Button

Tags: ios, xcode, swift5

How to make the return key in TextField keyboard do the same job of Sign-in button

Please help me as I can't delcare the action buttin inside textFiledShouldReturn func

check my code below:

```
class Sign_in: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.Password.delegate = self
    self.Password.returnKeyType = .go
  }


// To make the return Key in Keyboard do dismiss when pressed
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()

    return  true
}
```

//Auth Codes

```
@IBOutlet weak var Email: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var Password : UITextField!

@IBAction func signIN (_ sender : UIButton) {

    Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: self.Email.text!, password: self.Password.text!) { (status, error) in
        if error == nil {
            print ("Sign in succeeded")
        } else {
            print ("username or password mismatched: " + error.debugDescription)
        }
    }
}
```

I know that I can copy the whole Sign in Auth code to entire textFiledShouldReturn func but that is too bad... so is there is any better way to do that?

Comment: Just call resignFirstResponder on your password text field.

Comment: @badhanganesh how?? the password textField is ( Outlet ) !!

Comment: Sorry I think I mistook your question. You can just have your auth code in a separate method (say, login) and that method can be called from both button action and shouldReturn.

Comment: @badhanganesh Yes good idea thank you very much fro your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a method for your auth login and call that method from your `textFieldShouldReturn` and button action, like below:

```
class Sign_in: UIViewController {
    @IBAction func signIN (_ sender : UIButton) {
        authLogin()
    }

    func authLogin() {
         Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: self.Email.text!, password: self.Password.text!) { (status, error) in
            if error == nil {
                print ("Sign in succeeded")
            } else {
                print ("username or password mismatched: " + error.debugDescription)
            }
        }
    }
}

extension Sign_in : UITextFieldDelegate {
    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        authLogin()
        return  true
    }
}
```